# Is there a way to reference questions that are structured the same in for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement

I want to call on a list of sub-questions that are structured the same way (e.g. E1_1, E1_2, E1_3, etc.) in a for loop. My goal is to replace all instances of 0 in these sub-questions to a missing value (None) based on if a respondent indicated that they were supposed to answer the main question (e.g. if df['EOPS'] is equal to 1, this means a respondent indicated that they are answering 'E' questions) and if they did not respond to the main question (e.g. if 'E1' was not answered,'E1_1', 'E1_2', 'E1_3', etc should be recoded as NaNs)

Code:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], columns=['EOPS', 'E1', 'E1_1', 'E1_2', 'E1_3', 'E2', 'E2_1', 'E2_2', 'E2_3', 'E3', 'E3_1', 'E3_2', 'E3_3'])

list_of_questions = ['E1', 'E2', 'E3'] # each question in list has associated questions 'E1_1', 'E1_2', 'E1_3', 'E2_1', 'E2_2', 'E2_3', etc.

for question in list_of_questions:
   for i in range(1,3):
      if df['E1'] == 0 & df['EOPS'] == 1:
         df['E1_`i''] = np.where(data_final['E1_`i''] == 0, None, data_final['E1_`i''])
```

How can I call on the sub-questions in this loop? For those familiar with Stata this would done with `` `' `` quotes as I did above around the `i`, but I'm wondering if the same can be done in Python.

What I'm hoping to achieve is this:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]], columns=['EOPS', 'E1', 'E1_1', 'E1_2', 'E1_3', 'E2', 'E2_1', 'E2_2', 'E2_3', 'E3', 'E3_1', 'E3_2', 'E3_3'])
```

Thanks!

Comment: What did you mean exactly with `df['E1_i'] = df['E1_i'] == 1`? Is it condition like where values are equals to 1 in given df['E1_i'] columns?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but maybe you're looking for `enumerate()`? enumerate returns both the index and the item, so you can do `for index, question in enumerate(list_of_questions):` and then have your index that you can call on.

Comment: Yes that's correct. What I'm really asking for is the way to properly call on ```'E1_1', 'E1_2', 'E1_3',``` to do this loop etc.

Comment: what are you trying to do? select a set of data within a column `E1_i` or select multiple columns? a proper [mcve] would go a long way.

Comment: @Datanovice thanks for you helpful suggestions. I edited the main code to actually reflect what I'm looking for. I want to loop through each sub-question of E1 to replace the values with NaN if ```df['E1'] == 0 & df['EOPS'] == 1```

Comment: can you post your sample data and output? would be easier to provide a solution that way. from what it sounds like, either `np.where` or `.loc` would work.

Comment: @Datanovice I'm new to stackoverflow, so I did my best to update my question with my end result and included sample data

Comment: @pythonnewbiebb that's a very good reproducible example +1 from me.

Comment: _My goal is to replace all instances of 0 in these sub-questions to a missing value (None) based on if a respondent indicated that they were supposed to answer the main question..._ I'm curious, why do you want to do this? I'm wondering whether a Pandas DataFrame is really the best data structure to use here. Can you share a bit more about your program as a whole, some more context?

Comment: I forgot to add that it still isn't entirely clear to me what you're even trying to do. I'm looking at the example input and output, but they don't seem very representative.

Comment: _replace all instances of 0 in these sub-questions to a missing value (None)_ Your example output seems to indicate that you want to indicate the data is missing only if **all the columns** are 0, whereas that sentence obviously implies that **any value of 0** should be replaced. There is actually a **third** possibility, since in your example code you perform the replacement by group the questions by `E_n`. **Can you definitively clarify what you're trying to do?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need to loop, we can take advantage of `.any` and `.loc` to assign to your columns inplace

for e.g

```
import numpy as np    
cols = df.iloc[:,1:].columns.tolist()

df.loc[((df[cols] == 0).all(axis=1)) & (df['EOPS'] == 1), cols] = np.nan
```

another method to select your columns :

```
cols = df.filter(regex='E\d+').columns
```

---

result:

```
   EOPS   E1  E1_1  E1_2  E1_3   E2  E2_1  E2_2  E2_3   E3  E3_1  E3_2  E3_3
0     1  1.0   0.0   1.0   1.0  1.0   0.0   1.0   1.0  1.0   0.0   1.0   1.0
1     0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
2     1  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure based on your question but I suspect `zip` is what you're looking for:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = ["a", "b", "c"]
for x, y in zip(a, b):
    print(x, y)
```

Will give:

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

Another approach that gives the same results without `zip` (you should use `zip` though, iterators are *usually* better):

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = ["a", "b", "c"]
for i, x in enumerate(a):
    print(x, b[i])
```